# Laravel Socialite Request Returns Null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-socialite, laravel-request

I'm using Laravel Socialite 5.0.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function login(AuthenticateUser $authenticateUser, Request $request){
    return $authenticateUser->execute($request->has('code'));
}
```

`$request->has('code')` always returns null. Why is that?
Providing my AuthenticateUser class I see this as a redirect/request problem.

```
<?php 

namespace App;

use Laravel\Socialite\Contracts\Factory as Socialite;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard as Guard;
use App\Repositories\UserRepository as UserRepository;
use Log;

class AuthenticateUser {

    private $users;
    private $socialite;
    private $auth;

    public function __construct (UserRepository $users, Socialite $socialite, Guard $auth) {
        $this->users = $users;
        $this->socialite = $socialite;
        $this->auth = $auth;
    }

    public function execute ($hasCode) {
        if( ! $hasCode){
            Log::info('1');
            return $this->getAuthorizationFirst();
        }
        Log::info('2');
        $user = $this->socialite->driver('github')->user();
    }

    public function getAuthorizationFirst(){
        return $this->socialite->driver('github')->redirect();
    }

}
```

Adding the AuthController Class for reference:

```
class AuthController extends Controller {

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Registration & Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users, as well as the
    | authentication of existing users. By default, this controller uses
    | a simple trait to add these behaviors. Why don't you explore it?
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Create a new authentication controller instance.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard  $auth
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Registrar  $registrar
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Guard $auth, Registrar $registrar)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth;
        $this->registrar = $registrar;

        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'getLogout']);
    }

    public function login(AuthenticateUser $authenticateUser, Request $request){
        Log::info('_'.$request->has('code').'_');
        return $authenticateUser->execute($request->has('code'));
    }

}
```

Comment: I am following the laracast tutorial: https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5/episodes/9 
But just not able to pass through this has('code').

Comment: How does the form that triggers the function look like?

Comment: Its not a form. I just trigger the route.
<a class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-github" href={{ url('/github/auth') }}>
        <i class="fa fa-github"></i>
        Sign in with Github
      </a>

Comment: can you post your authenticate user class?

Comment: Did you provide the correct token inside the services.php file?

Comment: Yes. I am able to receive the code from github as well.

Comment: But the page redirect fails. Essentially nothing happens after the url gets updated.

Comment: Added the AuthController class. The log always produces a null string! Guessing it to be a request problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89354/discussion-between-szenis-and-aditya-kappagantula).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the return url route!
I was returning to a wrong route from the application.